# @extend class declared after

Tags: css, sass, stylus

good day all. I'm using stylus and have the following css structure:

main.styl

```
@import '_file1'

.myClass {
    color: blue
}
```

file1.styl

```
.left {
    @extend .myClass
    background: white
}
```

This returns an error because .myClass is defined after the @extend. is there a way to correctly use it that way?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't import the file after  `.myClass`?

Answer (score 0):

I think its impossible. It's against to sass logic.